# How to check if File is a Java class

Tags: java, io

I have a `java.io.File` class with a link to a resource. I want to check if this file is a Java class.
It is possible to check the file extension... BUT this method does not suit me, since anyone can create a file with the .class extension, but logically the file itself will not be a Java class.

Comment: In general, it is harder to determine what something _is_ than to determine what something _is not_. For example, a file without a class extension isn't a Java class; a file without the Java class magic number (0xcafebabe) isn't a Java class etc. You can only really determine that it *is* a Java class by attempting to load it with Java.

Comment: I can use the Class.forName (...) method, but if the specified file is not a class, an error will occur.
I don't know what to do better.

Comment: You can always catch the exception that happens when you load it and if you do, you'll know it's not a Java class (or a malformed one or one missing its dependency or ...). Note that loading unknown/untrusted Java classes is probably not a good idea security-wise.

Answer (score 0):

All Java files start with the magic number 0xCAFEBABE, so this should do the trick

```
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(outFile);
        byte[] magicNumber = new byte[4];
        is.read(magicNumber);
        is.close();

        Arrays.equals(new byte[]{(byte) 0xca, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xbe}, magicNumber);
```